# If one dataframe value exists in another dataframe, then get a value from the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a beginner in Python and this is my first time using pandas. I would like to create a code to analyze my data but it's not working.

I have 2 dataframes: first one has the information about how user rated a movie ('user id', 'movie id', 'rating') and second one had the information about the users ('user id', 'gender', 'age')

With help of pandas I would like my code to perform a loop so that for each row in the first dataframe,
you get the **gender** from the second dataframe of the same user id in the current row in the first dataframe.

Below is a simplified version of my datasets and codes

```
d1 = {'user id': [4, 2, 7]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
d2 = {'user id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'gender': ['M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    if row["user id"].isin.(df2.user id) and df2["gender"] == "M":
        //execute some code
    if row["user id"].isin.(df2.user id) and df2["gender"] == "F":
        //execute some code
```

That is as far as I got with my code but I don't know how to code so to get the gender of a specified row.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` loops are slower. You can avoid it by using [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
In [2142]: df1.merge(df2, on='user id')
Out[2142]: 
   user id gender
0        4      F
1        2      F
2        7      M
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Since there are more columns in the actual dataframe I will check how I can merge certain columns.